# HTML Text Display next to menu

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of learning HTML & CSS and I'm building a website for a homework I have. I've successfully created a menu inside a border. I want some text to appear next to it, but instead it appears on top of it (because I've put the code on top of the menu). I just want the text to be next to the menu(after the vertical line of course) and work with the paragraphs indipendently with the menu. How can I achieve that? That's what I mean(don't mind the characters, they're Greek):

[image]

As you can see, while I'm writing on the paragraph, the menu with the options keeps moving down and I don't want that.

Here's my code:

```css
#first {
  border: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center
}

#second {
  border: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left
}

.target span {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

#line {
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  top: 130px;
}

#transparent-line {
  border-left: 3px solid white;
  height: 250px;
}

#description {
  text-indent: 300px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <h1>Αρχική σελίδα</h1>
</div>


<div id="second">
  <div id="description">

    <p> Καλωσήρθατε στον ιστόχωρο για το μάθημα "Εκμάθηση HTML". Η ιστοσελίδα αυτή δημιουργήθηκε με σκοπό να διευκολύνει τους φοιτητές κατά την εκμάθηση της HTML. </p>
    <p> Επιπλέον,

  </div>
  <h4 class="target"><span>Αρχική σελίδα</span></h4>
  <h4 class="target"><span>Ανακοινώσεις</span></h4>
  <h4 class="target"><span>Επικοινωνία</span></h4>
  <h4 class="target"><span>Έγγραφα μαθήματος</span></h4>
  <h4 class="target"><span>Εργασίες</span></h4>
  <div id="line"></div>
  <div id="transparent-line"></div>
```

Comment: adding `float: right;` to the styling of `#description` could make it work.

Comment: Yes it works but it moves my whole paragraph to the right side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#first{
     border:3px; 
     border-style:solid; 
     border-color: black; 
     padding: 1em; 
     text-align: center
    }

    #second{
     border:3px; 
     border-style:solid; 
     border-color: black;
     text-align: left
      width:100%;
      float:left;
      padding:0 0 0 15px;
    }

    .target span{
     background-color: grey;
     color: white;
    }

   .menu-items{width:25%;float:left;border-right:3px solid #000;}
   .description{width:70%;float:right;padding:15px;}
```

```html
<div id="first">
     <h1>Αρχική σελίδα</h1>
    </div>


    <div id="second">
     <div class="menu-items">
        <h4 class="target"><span>Αρχική σελίδα</span></h4>
        <h4 class="target"><span>Ανακοινώσεις</span></h4>
        <h4 class="target"><span>Επικοινωνία</span></h4>
        <h4 class="target"><span>Έγγραφα μαθήματος</span></h4>
        <h4 class="target"><span>Εργασίες</span></h4>
     </div>
      <div id="description">

      <p> Καλωσήρθατε στον ιστόχωρο για το μάθημα "Εκμάθηση HTML". Η ιστοσελίδα αυτή δημιουργήθηκε με σκοπό να διευκολύνει τους φοιτητές κατά την εκμάθηση της HTML. </p>
      <p> Επιπλέον,

     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok, with a little bit of modifications it works. Why did you add the vertical line? I already have one. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the targets divs in div and use `display:flex` also change order of html

```css
        #first{
         border:3px; 
         border-style:solid; 
         border-color: black; 
         padding: 1em; 
         text-align: center
        }

        #second{
         border:3px; 
         border-style:solid; 
         border-color: black;  
         display:flex;
         
        }
h4{
min-width: 150px;
}
        .target span{
         background-color: grey;
         color: white;
          min-width:150px;
        }

        #description{
         font-size: 18px;
          border-left:1px solid black;
          padding:5px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="first">
         <h1>Αρχική σελίδα</h1>
</div>

<div id="second">
<div>
   <h4 class="target"><span>Αρχική σελίδα</span></h4>
   <h4 class="target"><span>Ανακοινώσεις</span></h4>
   <h4 class="target"><span>Επικοινωνία</span></h4>
   <h4 class="target"><span>Έγγραφα μαθήματος</span></h4>
   <h4 class="target"><span>Εργασίες</span></h4>
</div>
<div id="description">
   <p> Καλωσήρθατε στον ιστόχωρο για το μάθημα "Εκμάθηση HTML". Η ιστοσελίδα αυτή δημιουργήθηκε με σκοπό να διευκολύνει τους φοιτητές κατά την εκμάθηση της HTML. </p>
   <p> Επιπλέον,
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Swap the HTML for the "nav" and your "content" and then wrap them in divs. This will allow you to control both elements of your webpage with greater accuracy.

2) Float both wrapper divs to the left and apply a width to them. This will bring both elements into the same line and then give you to control on how much of the page you want your navigation and your content to take up.

```css
#first{
     border:3px; 
     border-style:solid; 
     border-color: black; 
     padding: 1em; 
     text-align: center
    }

    #second{
     border:3px; 
     border-style:solid; 
     border-color: black; 
     padding: 1em; 
     text-align: left
    }

    .target span{
     background-color: grey;
     color: white;
    }

    #line{
     border-left: 3px solid black;
      height: 500px;
      position: absolute;
     position: absolute;
        left: 15%;
        margin-left: -3px;
        top: 130px;
    }

    #transparent-line{
     border-left: 3px solid white;
      height: 250px;
    }

    #description{
     text-indent: 300px;
     font-size: 18px;
    }

    .nav{
        float:left;
        width:20%;
    }

    .content{
        float:left;
        width:80%;
    }
```

```html
 

   <div id="first">
    <h1>Αρχική σελίδα</h1>
</div>


<div id="second">
    <div class="nav">    
        <h4 class="target"><span>Αρχική σελίδα</span></h4>
        <h4 class="target"><span>Ανακοινώσεις</span></h4>
        <h4 class="target"><span>Επικοινωνία</span></h4>
        <h4 class="target"><span>Έγγραφα μαθήματος</span></h4>
        <h4 class="target"><span>Εργασίες</span></h4> 
    </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div id="description">
        
                <p> Καλωσήρθατε στον ιστόχωρο για το μάθημα "Εκμάθηση HTML". Η ιστοσελίδα αυτή δημιουργήθηκε με σκοπό να
                    διευκολύνει τους φοιτητές κατά την εκμάθηση της HTML. </p>
                <p> Επιπλέον,
        
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="line"></div>
    <div id="transparent-line"></div>
```